# How can I allow multiple styles of geometry in Survey123

Tags: online, survey123

I'm creating a survey to capture local knowledge within my company. I've got a single select choice to determine a POI or an area etc. When it comes to capturing the area on a map I can only see that I can add either a point, line or polygon capture question. Is there a way to give the user a choice between the three that won't involve adding three separate map capture sections to my survey?